# Accessibility: Using media queries to hide text

Tags: html, css, accessibility

The current methods for making [invisible content](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques)—that is hide text from screens but make it available to screen readers—seem rather hacky. Currently bootstrap has an [`sr-only`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ff29c1224c20b8fcf2d1e7c28426470f1dc3e40d/scss/mixins/_screen-reader.scss#L6-L15) mixin defined as:

```css
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}
```

My question is: Can this be done easier with a simple screen only media query? In particular I want to know if it is acceptable to hide, say a heading in the app below, with the following media query and rule:

```css
@media only screen {
  h2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

In other words: will the media query `@media only screen` apply to screen readers as well as screens?

Expand this snippet to see where this might be useful.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

window.addEventListener('hashchange', ({ newURL }) => {
  const { hash } = new URL(newURL);
  
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section.matches(hash)) {
      section.style.display = null;
    } else {
      section.style.display = 'none'
    }
  });
  
  anchors.forEach(anchor => {
    if (anchor.href === newURL) {
      anchor.parentNode.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      anchor.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
article {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: #adadad;
}

nav .active a {
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen {
  h2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <nav>
    <ol>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#chapter-1">Chapter 1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#chapter-2">Chapter 2</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#chapter-3">Chapter 3</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>

  <section id="chapter-1">
    <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
    <p>The heading above is redundant for sighted users.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="chapter-2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
    <p>They can infer it from the nav bar to the left.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="chapter-3" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Chapter 3</h2>
    <p>But screen readers might benefit from having it there.</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Things classed with `sr-only` should be visible to screen readers, but *not* screens. Will the media query `only screen` apply to screen readers as well, not reading the content of the hidden element?

Comment: Ah, I see now. media query only screen will STILL apply to screen readers. There is no way to selectively target and hide things from a screen reader using a media query. At least that feature is not out yet.

The screen is meant to capture screen devices. The thing is, screen readers work on phones, monitors, tablets. Every device. I hope that makes sense. But @media only screen will still target screen readers. Every media query will.

Comment: According to https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media-type, screen readers should use media speech and should ignore NOT use media screen.  However, I believe this has not yet been implemented across the board with screen readers, if it has been implemented at all.  Note that is a draft document.

Comment: You raised an interesting question. The `sr-only ` is around for a long time, and it's still a hack. Why is there no better standardized way to hide an element from visual media? One that is backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is less "hacky", but it's certainly a little simpler.  If an element is referenced by [`aria-labelledby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-labelledby) or [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby) and that element is hidden, it will still be used in the [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2).

So instead of using an `sr-only` class to hide the text, you can *really* hide it.

```
<span id="foo" style="display:none;">you can't see me</span>
...
<a href="#" id="myself" aria-labelledby="myself foo">hello</a>
```

When you navigate to the link, the screen reader will say: *"hello you can't see me"*

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Thanks. Do you know if the common screen readers actually respect that? afaik even labelledby itself is not supported by some?

Comment: So for labeling sections with a hidden heading you can do:

`<section aria-labelledby="chapter-1-label"><h3 id="chapter-1-label" style="display:none;">Chapter 1</h3></section>`

Comment: @Andy yes `aria-labelledby` is supported by **all** screen readers.  there are times where the label *might* be ignored, but there are good reasons for it as explained on https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support

Comment: @RúnarBerg while you *could* do that, i would initially question that specific example because you have a hidden heading (h3) and headings are generally great for **all** users, whether sighted or not, so visually hiding the heading is not generally recommended, but your example would work in that i could navigate by landmarks with the screen reader and hear a "region" landmark with a label of "chapter 1" even though the heading itself would be invisible.

Comment: @slugolicious In my case the heading is redundant for sighted users since they get the heading from the visually strongest item in the `<nav>` menu next to it. Non-sighted users and crawlers may need it though since the nav menu is logically away from the section.

Comment: @RúnarBerg not sure i follow that.  your example had a <section> with an embedded <h3>.  i didn't see anything about a <nav> or other "strong" text.

Comment: @slugolicious See the full version in the snippet in the original question

Comment: @RúnarBerg ah, never saw that originally.  thanks for pointing it out.  it was in a collapsed section that didn't have `aria-expanded`.  you example makes more sense now

Comment: @slugolicious Sorry about that. Stackoverflow offers an expandable option for snippets. Since this part was an in depth more detailed part of the question, I took advantage of it. I wonder why stackoverflow doesn’t add an `aria-expanded` there or (better yet) implement it with the semantically correct `<details>` / `<summary>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. So you're trying to hide the text visually(sighted) but have it available for screen readers(blind). Can you explain a bit more of what you're trying to achieve?

If so, I don't see anything wrong with the bootstrap sr-only... Here's an alternative.

```
.hidden 
{position:absolute;
left:-10000px;
top:auto;
width:1px;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;}
```

However, if you're trying to hide it from a screen reader, I would simply use the aria-hidden="true."

```
display:none;
```

Will not be read to a screen reader.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the bootstrap method. But over the past decade it has changed significantly, and I feel like it will change in the future as people find new ways to achieve this. That is why I'm asking if a simple (and less hacky) media query can do the job.

Comment: ah, I see, well WebAim, in my opinion, is the leading accessibility experts as of right now. I'm going to refer you to this article on why they chose their code snippet and wrote it the way they did.

https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/